# Copy constructors instead of Clone in java

Tags: java, reference, clone, copy-constructor

I am trying to implement a copy constructor in java. I am facing a problem with non primitive type fields of the class. While creating a new copy, it is sharing the members. For Example

```
public class Bad implements Cloneable {
    private ArrayList<Integer> a;
    private Object c;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bad b1 = new Bad();
        b1.a.add(10);

        System.out.println(b1.a);
        Bad b2 = b1.clone();
        b2.a.add(12);

        System.out.println(b1.a);   
    }

    Bad() {
        a = new ArrayList<>();
        c = null;
    }

    Bad(Bad b) {
        a = b.a;
        c = b.c;
    }

    public Bad clone() {
        return new Bad(this);
    }
}
```

And the result is :

```
[10]
[10, 12]
```

I don't want this to happen. Take this as an example. My original problem consists of even more fields that are user defined.
Or are there any libraries which do the work for me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `a = new ArrayList<>(b.a);` this should create a new arrayList with the contents from `b.a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integer is immutable but you need to create a totally new **ArrayList**, and I mean here :

```
Bad(Bad b) {
    a = b.a;
    c = b.c;
}
```

do instead

```
Bad(Bad b) {
    a = new ArrayList<>(b.a);
    c = // this here must be copy constructed too
}
```

and then you will get

> [10]
>
> [10]

Comment: the actual param has the `Integer` type whereas the field is still an `Object`. You have to find out a coping mechanism for that as well as for the list

Answer (score 3):

Simple rules for a copy constructor:

- **primitive values** may be copied as-is; they are just values without a separate identity
- **references to immutable types** (eg. String, Integer, any enum class constant) may also be copied as-is; although the original and the copied objects will share the same reference, the referred object is immutable and will never change
- **references to mutable types** (eg. Date, ArrayList, any array) must be copied to a new instance of the type; otherwise the original and the copied object will share a reference to the same mutable field object (which is not what you want)

Making a copy of an object that contains only fields with primitive and immutable values is easy mode.

Copying an object whose fields contain mutable objects can make the process arduous and expensive depending on how complex the mutable object is (imagine an ArrayList that contains a Map whose values are also Maps).  Making a new copy of the mutable field is, however, essential if you wish to have a safe copy.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way would be creating a new instance of the list instead of passing a reference to the original list.

```
Bad(Bad b) {
  a = new ArrayList<>(b.a);
  c = b.c; // this should call clone or something similar as well
}
```

Also note that if you would have some non-primitive type within the list of b.a, then you would have to copy/clone all the sub-elements as well (it is not needed now as you have Integer in it which is not mutable).